# JPOS 8583 Bitmap not getting properly

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I'm trying to build a simulator in java using jpos.Please find the String  at my end during sending the data to server.this string is generated from another simulator as below 
String r:A\11\A8\E0\90\
on the other hand from our simulator string are as 
String :r:A\11\A8\E0?\

So My Question is  Iam using IFB_BITMAP Class of bitmap field  why 90 value is converterd to ? special character?

Comment: Hello please elaborate, you are not saying how you are generating you bitmap, also those strings doesn't look as bitmaps at all to me what do that \'s mean? are separator of bytes being represented in hexa?. What are the present fields in you message? Jpos just generate the bitmap according to the fields you set. If you don't provide that information we cannot help you at all, also that ? may mean anything depending on how you are trying to display your data. For instance may be a form for your terminal to say that it is an undisplayable character.

Comment: ----ISO MESSAGE-----
  MTI : 0200
    Field-2 : 169991000501589186
    Field-3 : 301000
    Field-4 : 000001000000
    Field-7 : 0616032008
    Field-11 : 177
    Field-12 : 032008
    Field-13 : 0616
    Field-15 : 1115
    Field-18 : 0000
    Field-24 : 001
    Field-28 : 00000000
    Field-32 : 1158943000
    Field-33 : 06000001
    Field-35 : 279991000501589186=0903121550
    Field-37 : 082400096515
    Field-41 : 0540
    Field-42 : 000540
    Field-43 : AAA
    Field-49 : 586
    Field-52 : 51A14E71F3B8CC08

Comment: this is the final string of above message that recived at server end

\00\F30200r:A\11\A8\E0?\00181699910005015891863010000000010000000616032008000177032008061611150000001000000000101158943000080600000129279991000501589186=09031215500824000965150540    000540         AAA                                     58651A14E71F3B8CC08

Comment: Why don't you show the jpos code that generates that? And what is exactly what leaves jpos? I mean seen from the jpos perspective, you can add a logger to the packager and the channel to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start off the jPOS client simulator instead?
See http://jpos.org/doc/jPOS-EE.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the BITMAP type IFB_BITMAP, it uses the Binary Form, where the bitmaps are represented in special characters. For example, please see the below ISO MESSAGE:

```
0200r8dﾁ)￡ﾐ
```

But when you change to IFA_BITMAP i.e. to ASCII/HEX, the following bitmaps will be generated:

```
02007238648129E19008
```

If the HOST doesnt accept the ASCII format, you have to send the binary, which you are already doing.